# Retrospectively closing a NetCDF file created with Fortran

Tags: fortran, netcdf

I'm running a distributed model stripped to its bare minimum below:

```
integer, parameter :: &
nx = 1200,& ! Number of columns in grid
ny = 1200,& ! Number of rows in grid
nt = 6000   ! Number of timesteps

integer :: it ! Loop counter

real :: var1(nx,ny), var2(nx,ny), var3(nx,ny), etc(nx,ny) 

! Create netcdf to write model output
call check( nf90_create(path="out.nc",cmode=nf90_clobber, ncid=nc_out_id) )

! Loop over time
do it = 1,nt

   ! Calculate a lot of variables 
   ...

   ! Write some variables in out.nc at each timestep
   CALL check( nf90_put_var(ncid=nc_out_id, varid=var1_varid, values=var1, &
    start = (/ 1, 1, it /), count = (/ nx, ny, 1 /)) )

   ! Close the netcdf otherwise it is not readable: 
   if (it == nt)  call check( nf90_close(nc_out_id) )

enddo
```

I'm in the development stage of the model so, it inevitably crashes at unexpected points (usually at the `Calculate a lot of variables` stage), which means that, if the model crashes at timestep `it =3000`, 2999 timesteps will be written to the netcdf output file, but I will not be able to read the file because the file has not been closed. Still, the data have been written: I currently have a 2GB out.nc file that I can't read. When I `ncdump` the file it shows

```
netcdf out.nc {
dimensions:
         x = 1400 ;
         y = 1200 ;
         time = UNLIMITED ; // (0 currently)
variables:
         float var1 (time, y, x) ;
data:
}
```

My questions are: (1) Is there a way to close the file retrospectively, even outside Fortran, to be able to read the data that have already been written? (2) Alternatively, is there another way to write the file in Fortran that would make the file readable even without closing it?

Comment: You can call [`nf90_sync`](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/netcdf-4/newdocs/netcdf-f90/NF90_005fSYNC.html) at each loop step (or some multiple of loop steps), which should write buffered data to the file and may solve some of your problems. I don't know whether it is possible to retrospectively close the file.

Comment: Calling `nf90_sync` should work. Another option could be to create the file with the `NF90_SHARE` flag. It's probably less messy than explicitly synchronizing the files all the time.

Comment: You can actually create a MWE in fortran, I do not see a problem here. And it would be good, because it may actually be important where the program crashes.However, syncing as previous comments suggest, should do the trick and if not, there is also an option to close/open file in each step (there is some overhead, so not suggested solution) or write more and smaller files and merge them later into HDF5 logical group.

Comment: @SteveES Thank you, `nf90_sync` worked for the new files I'm creating.

Comment: @RussF, Thanks, `nf90_share` also worked. I opted for this solution in the end.

Comment: @kakk11 The issue wasn't about not being able to create a MWE in fortran, rather not knowing how to create a MWE than unexpectedly crashes.

Comment: @RussF, I've put our commented answers into a "proper" answer with more explanation.

Comment: @SnowFrog Re: MWE that unexpectedly crashes. Something simple like calling a crashing subroutine at random iteration step would not work?

Comment: I guess @kakk11 is pointing out that some of your description could have been written as code with comments, e.g. pointing out where you are getting crashes. Advice might be different if crashes mainly occur within a loop or not, for example. You wouldn't need to put in most code details, maybe just an example of your structure, with relevant calls to nf90 routines, and comments saying things like `! Sometimes crashes in this loop`. Having said that, I did understand the question.

Comment: @SteveES I have edited the question as you suggested.

Comment: Couldn't this `call check( nf90_close(nc_out_id) )` go outside the `do` loop, given that it is only called on the last iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [`nf90_close`](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/netcdf-4/newdocs/netcdf-f90/NF90_005fCLOSE.html) is called, buffered output is written to disk and the file ID is relinquished so it can be reused. The problem is most likely due to buffered output not having been written to the disk when the program terminates due to a crash, meaning that only the changes you made in "define mode" are present in the file (as shown by ncdump).

You therefore need to force the data to be written to the disk more often. There are three ways of doing this (as far as I am aware).

- [`nf90_sync`](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/netcdf-4/newdocs/netcdf-f90/NF90_005fSYNC.html#NF90_005fSYNC) - which synchronises the buffered data to disk when called. This gives you the most control over when to output data (every loop step, or every n loop steps, for example), which can allow you to optimize for speed vs robustness, but introduces more programming and checking overhead for you.
- **Thanks to @RussF for this idea.** Creating or opening the file using the `nf90_share` flag. This is the recommended approach if the netCDF file is intended to be used by multiple readers/writers simultaneously. It is essentially the same as an automatic implementation of `nf90_sync` for writing data. It gives less control, but also less programming overhead. Note that:

  > This only applies to netCDF-3 classic or 64-bit offset files.
- Finally, an option I wouldn't recommend, but am including for completeness (and I guess there may be situations where this is the best option, although none spring to mind) - closing and reopening the file. I don't recommend this, because it will slow down your program, and adds greater possibility of causing errors.

Comment: I would add an option of splitting the file into smaller pieces as well. I generally agree that closing and opening the file at each iteration is not good performance wise, but why it could cause more errors is unclear.

Comment: @kakk11, Fair point, I will add that in as another suggestion, unless you would rather suggest an edit, or provide as an answer yourself?

Comment: @kakk11 As for causing errors, I guess it's more "superstition" than fact, but my reasoning is based on an accumulation of small risks of causing an error (e.g. when connecting to disk/attempting to open/close a file) - each time is not more/less likely to fail, but the more times you call these functions, the more likely overall there is to be an error. Opening and closing involves more of these potentials for error each time, so is more error prone. (now I wait to be shot down...)